# How to fetch record of database table using ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible

> The error appears to be in '/home/jasmi/sprint5/us2/zuul-config/scenario/test/testservice.yaml':fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "missing required arguments: name"}

```yaml
- name: Access MariaDB in Docker Container
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Execute SQL query
      community.mysql.mysql_db:
        login_user: "{{ login_user }}"
        login_password: "{{ login_password }}"
        login_host: "{{ login_host }}"
        login_db: "{{ login_db }}"
        query: "{{ query }}"
      register: sql_result

    - name: Display SQL result
      debug:
        var: sql_result
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `- name: select uuid from zuul_buildset  table
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    name: run MySQL query
    mysql_query:
      login_user: zuul
      login_password: root
      db: zuuldb
      query: SELECT uuid  FROM zuul_buildset
    register: select_uuid_from_zuul`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"A malformed block was encountered while loading **tasks** ...
should be a **list** or None but is ... **AnsibleMapping**"*

A: In Ansible, *tasks* is a **list** of tasks. In other words, a task must be an item of the **list** *tasks*:

```yaml
- name: Select uuid from zuul_buildset  table
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: Run MySQL query
      mysql_query:
        login_user: zuul-data
        login_password: root
        db: zuul
        query: SELECT uuid  FROM zuul_buildset
      register: select_uuid_from_zuul
```

(not tested)